# Org function to estimate number of hours of all remaining tasks

Tags: org-mode

I use Org mode for my todo-list and to track habits. I find it great to look at the past and review the time I spent on each task. I am looking for something that does the same for tasks yet to finish, for example compute the average time taken by completed tasks at level 2 (`** DONE ...`) and multiply it by the number of level 2 tasks remaining `(** TODO ...`).

This would help me prioritize, as I have a sense that the amount of tasks that I commit to has been steadily growing.

Does this functionality exist natively or in a package?

### Update with example

Here is an example of an Org buffer:

```
* sprint
** TODO task 1

** TODO task 2

** TODO task 3

*** TODO sub-task 31

*** TODO sub-task 32

** DONE task 10
CLOSED: [2019-12-19 Thu 12:17]
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-12-14 Sat 18:37]--[2019-12-14 Sat 19:37] =>  1:00
:END:

** DONE task 11
CLOSED: [2019-12-19 Thu 18:39]
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-12-19 Thu 17:24]--[2019-12-19 Thu 19:24] =>  2:00
:END:

*** DONE sub-task 12
CLOSED: [2019-12-22 Sun 18:22]
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-12-22 Sun 18:01]--[2019-12-22 Sun 19:01] =>  1:00
:END:
```

A level 3 task with `*** DONE` takes on average 1h, a level 2 task alone with `** DONE` takes on average 1h30. I would like an output such as:

```
Org buffer <name>:
1 level 3 task(s) completed, 1:00 on average
2 level 2 task(s) completed, 1:30 on average (2:00 with children)

2 level 3 task(s) remaining, 2:00 left (estimated)
3 level 2 task(s) remaining, 4:30 remaining (6:30 with children)
```

Comment: Can you also add an example and the expected result.

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Usually one gives premilary effort estimations to each task maybe as effort points. For calculating the remaining effort the todo items are then weighted with these effort estimations. So you have actually a number of effort points for the done tasks and a number of effort points for the tasks to be done. The estimation of the rest work time results from (effort points todo)/(effort points done)*(work time spent).

Comment: @Tobias Sure, that would be great too! For tasks with missing effort estimates, one could impute the average at that level of hierarchy. Do you know any package that does it?